# HTML CSS Header image has an black stripe above hearder image that I can't seem to remove

Tags: html, css, image, web, header

Please check out

http://rainsongmanchesters.net/news.htm

and notice the black strip above the header image.

Now click here http://rainsongmanchesters.net/breedinfo.htm

and notice how there is no strip. Such a simple problem? It has defeated me for months! Using firebug, and just staring at the code for months has not produced any solutions. Please help!

Comment: Thank you all! I missed such a simple thing! Keep up the great work you two are so helpful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a < br /> in the header (line 16 of the source)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the extra break (< br />) at the top of the page.